# Impossible to generate the table "user"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

When I install *FOSUserBundle* ([official documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)), I try to generate my table `fos_user` using this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But console returns the following message

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata

I use Symfony 2.1 and the last version to FOSUserBundle.

**app/AppKernel.php** contains

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

**app/config/config.yml** contains

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Krpano\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

**src/Krpano/UserBundle/Entity/User.php** contains

```
namespace Krpano\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pouet")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

And when I try to access to my website I have this error:

> MappingException: The class 'Krpano\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity, Krpano\ServicesBundle\Entity

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you registered your UserBundle in AppKernel? I mean, do you have a line like new Krpano\UserBundle\KrpanoUserBundle(),?

Comment: Oops ... I forgot that part. It's OK now. Thank's a lot.

Comment: OK, I´ll add the solution as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 4):

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata

Implies that your entity is not registred because of a missing declaration in AppKernel.php.

Doctrine only search on bundle who are active.

After added the line :

```
new Krpano\UserBundle\KrpanoUserBundle(),
```

Like that:

```php
public function registerBundles()
    {
            $bundles = array(    
            ...
            new Krpano\UserBundle\KrpanoUserBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),    
            ...

        ); ...
```

Try this:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

If Doctrine return:

```
Database schema updated successfully! "1" queries were executed
```

Your problem is resolve.

My answer is just a completion to Carlos Granados answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
new Krpano\UserBundle\KrpanoUserBundle(),
```

To your app/AppKernel.php file

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and it was caused by having accidentally deleted the `@ORM\Entity()` line from my entity class. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just like you. You missed to create yml for Doctrine Entity. This file is needed for Doctrine to generate shema in your database.

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

Then in console update autoload for composer

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then call Doctrine schema builder

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize`

Also provokes this error, when running:

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

If you run:

`./composer.phar update`

again it all works again.