# FOSUserBundle command line user creation doesn't update database

Tags: database, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm suing FOSUserBundle with Symfony2.1.

I've tryed using this command line to create a new user:

```
php app/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com myPassword
```

and I gave the following response:

```
Created user testuser
```

Using phpMyAdmin, connecting to my database table, no user has been created and the table is still empty.

Can somebody help me?
I've followed step by step the implementation guide, but it doesn't work for me.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Copyng the entire folder and moving the project to a Windows based laptop, everything working fine! It is not a configuration issue.... Re-moving the project to my MAC laptop, it doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a user with calling just

```
php app/console fos:user:create
```

It's an interactive task i've been using few days ago, and was working fine then.

Comment: The table structure exists?

Can you create users by using the registration form provided by the bundle?

Comment: Yes, if I use the login form with existing records, it let me log in

Comment: and using the registration form? will it create new accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the table definition don't match with the map defined by FOSUserBundle

If you are using Doctrine then you can execute

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

If your definition is correct then you shouldn't see any SQL for the users table.

Comment: `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
`Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that you have not registred your Userbundle in AppKernel.php.

I don't want to duplicate my answers so check this link to link properly your entity and entity parent to table.

[Impossible to generate the table "user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145283/impossible-to-generate-the-table-user/12370525#12370525)

Cordialy